# Unable to Compile with ImportMany attribute

Tags: c#, .net, mef

As to total MEF newbie, I'm having a problem with my first test of MEF.  My problem code is below-

```
using System;
using GlobalInterfaces;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;

namespace GlobalInterfacesUnitTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class GlobalInterfacesUnitTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            [ImportMany(AllowRecomposition = true)]
            Lazy<IComponentGui, IImportComponentGuiCapabilites>[] Senders {get;set;}
        }
    }
}
```

The problem that I cannot get the compiler to find "ImportMany" attribute.  I've checked the references against several demos and copied their references and still have the same problem.  I cannot see what I'm overlooking.  I am using VS2010 / Net4.0.

Comment: The `ImportAttribute` is located in the assebly System.ComponentModle.Composition.  Follow Andrey's answer and make sure that the assembly is added as a reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't define properties inside method. Move it out to class. Try:

```
[TestClass]
public class GlobalInterfacesUnitTest
{
    [ImportMany(AllowRecomposition = true)]
    Lazy<IComponentGui, IImportComponentGuiCapabilites>[] Senders {get;set;}

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {

    }
}
```